# Tell me the difference b/w just width and height and (max/min)width and height?

Tags: html, css

What's the basic difference between [width and height] and max/min[width and height] and where should we use each of them?

Thanks in advance........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic difference is that width and height will specify the exact width and height of an object. Max/min width and height will specify the maximum or minimum height and width that an object needs to be.

Say you had a div that you wanted to load images into, but you wanted all images to be the no larger and no smaller then a specific width or height, then using min/max calls would be ideal.

In other cases, where you know the width and height (say for only a specific image) then you do not need max or min height/width calls.

It is also important to note that max/min height and width calls will over-ride height and width calls.

Here is some more information:

1. [CSS Height and Width](http://www.quackit.com/css/tutorial/css_height_width.cfm)
2. [CSS Tests - Min and Max](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/width.html)

Answer (score 1):

width/height give you the strict constraints. max-height/max-width tell your element to be **not wider/higher** than a certain value, but the element can still be smaller than that value.

max-height/width are commonly used when you want to make the site behave according to the screen it is viewed on, but to not be super huge on the large screens anyway. The same about the elements - you might want to accept images of any size, but want to make sure they are not breaking your site layout. Hence you use max-width/height.

They don't work in IE6 though. If you need to support min-width/height in IE6 you can use regular width/height. IE6 will treat them as minimum values anyway and will expand them in case content needs more space. Both min/max width/height work fine in IE7+

Comment: In fact `min-width` and `min-heigth` are mainly used to scale down images keeping their aspect ratio.

Comment: IE supports min/max height just fine. I think you have to go back to IE 6 before they break.

Comment: Thanks, @Quentin. Updated my answer with that info

Comment: what will happen if the content height grows more than the max-height or just height?